# Cypress won't start, blank screen. Mac m1

Tags: cypress

I recently started getting this error where cypress only shows a blank screen and I can't seem to figure it out yet.

I've tried:

- removing/reinstalling node_modules
- running yarn

My cypress version in package.json:
"cypress": "^10.3.0",

When I run `yarn cypress` I get this message, and cypress opens with a blank screen:

> objc[35990]: Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libANGLE-shared.dylib (0x222c25b50) and /Users/[username]/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLESv2.dylib (0x10923d3c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: I've also tried using rosetta ` softwareupdate --install-rosetta` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running again, after clearing cypress cache.

1. `npm uninstall -g cypress`
2. `npm i -g cypress@10.9`
3. `yarn cypress cache clear`
4. `yarn install`
5. run with `yarn cypress`

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Clear-Cypress-cache